# Is a dictionary within a dictionary with any list values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a question regarding dictionaries and how to tell if a dictionary appears in another. In the example below, I wish to check if d1 appears in d2 which as shown below:

```
d1 = { 'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3' }
d2 = { 'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4', 'e': '5' }
res = all(item in d2.items() for item in d1.items())
```

However, I have a case where I wish to be able to pass in a list of values and check that the values for a, b and any of the values of c appear in d2.

```
d1 = { 'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': ['3', '33', '333'] }
d2 = { 'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4', 'e': '5' }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The code you have works with `c` being a list too. What exactly is your doubt?

Comment: If the value of c in d1 is a list, the comparison fails as it looks to be trying to compare ['3', '33', '333'] with '3' and not if any of the list items equal d2's value of c

Comment: Ok so you just want to see if the `keys` of `d1` are present in `d2` irrespective of whether the values are same ?

Comment: I would like to see if all the keys and values in d1 appear in d2, but in the case that I have a value which contains a list in d1, then one of those values is the same for d2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, in your 2nd example, the result should be `True` since `'3'` belongs to list `d1['c']` and `d2['c'] == 3`.  If I am right then this might work:

```py
d1 = { 'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': ['3', '33', '333'] }
d2 = { 'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4', 'e': '5' }
res = all(item in d2.items() if not isinstance(item[1], list)
          else any((item[0], x) in d2.items() for x in item[1])
          for item in d1.items())
print(res)
```